# reading a text file line by line only with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want solution using Node.js, FileReader, or whatever else exept javascript!
Developing the html page, I encountered a problem as follows:
I get accurate results with this procedure, unfortunately the procedure remembers result of the first login page.  Whatever text file in the meantime change the content, the procedure returns the first result.
Can someone give advice!

```
var filePath = "../../dir/sub dir/text_file.txt";
function getBackData(filePath){
    var axd, i, artx, txli, tdr;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        axd = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        axd = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    axd.open('GET', filePath, true);
    axd.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(axd.readyState == 4 && axd.status == 200){
            artx = axd.responseText;
            txli = artx.split("\n"); 
            for(i = 0; i < txli.length; i++){
                alert(txli[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    axd.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try :`axd setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');`

Or try:   `axd.open('GET', filePath+'?_=' + new Date().getTime()), true);` This will prevent your server from using the cash, because each request is different.

Comment: Thanks to the rapid and efficient response O_Z,. I have used your advice and it works perfectly now!

Comment: I am grateful to others, whose tips were helpful too.

Comment: I'm sorry O_Z , I do not understand exactly what you mean by: 'Why did you unaccept me ?'

Comment: @Borache On my rank it shows that U accepted my answer and then unaccepted it.  Maybe a bug in stackoverflow.

Comment: I do not believe that it is a bug in the program, but a bug in my clumsiness! Namely, because this is my first post on this forum, I made a mess trying to checked all three responsive as useful, which obviously was not permitted. Now your response is marked as advice that I used with success. Although the other two councils were in the same direction. I sincerely apologize for the inconvenience. I owe you one.

Comment: @Borache It's OK :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the browser cache it. If you send a parameter which is almost always different like timestamp, you can disable the cache. Or you can try to use POST, since post request are never cached.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to request local files directly with ajax - you need a server to serve them. The browser is sandboxed and cannot generally open local files. This is a security measure - imagine what would happen if any website was allowed to open your files!

There are ways to set up a simple server for your images, like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). This allows you to serve files directly off a chosen directory, like so:

```
npm install -g http-server
http-server path-to-text-files/
```

*Then* you can request the files normally with ajax, at a path relative to the one your server is serving, like so:

```
url = "/dir/subdir/text-file.txt";
...
ajax.open('GET', url, true);
...
ajax.send(null);
```